# Equal height for divs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a [site](http://www.umestentorg.ru/). I want to make 3 vertical divs with equal height. For this purposes I change the height of last block in each column/div.

For example, the naming of 3 columns are:

```
.leftCenter
.rightCenter
.right
```

Now I wrote a code which set the equal height for `.leftCenter` and `.rightCenter`:

```
var left = $('.leftCenter').height();
var center = $('.rightCenter').height();

var news = $('#newItemsList').height();

if (center < left)
    $('.rightCenter').height(center + (left-center));
else if (center > left)
    $('#newItemsList').height(news + (center-left));
```

`news` is  the latest subblock in left column (there are 3 images in it). So, if central div is bigger than left div, I change the height of news to make them equal. [This code works in Firefox](http://www.umestentorg.ru/catalog.php?SECTION_ID=123), but doesn't work in Chrome. That's the first question. And the last is: how to make equal 3 divs (including right one).

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight

Comment: @nnnnnn That's not what I need, because I have to stretch not full div, but the last item inside it.

Comment: what if your user has javascript turned off? This is better handled with css, at least as a place to start - and can be further manipulated unobtrusively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make elements equal in height and width so I made the following function that allows you to define a height, or width, or really whatever at it. `refType` would be used if you sent a min-height and needed it to match the height of the tallest element.

```
elemsEqual = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
                'type' : 'height',
                'refType' : '',
                'elements' : [],
                'maxLen' : 450
            },
            settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options),
            max = 0;

        $(settings.elements.join(",")).each(function () {

            max = Math.max( max, parseInt( $(this).css(settings.type) ) );

            if(settings.refType.length) max = Math.max( max, parseInt( $(this).css(settings.refType) ) );

        });

        max = ((max < settings.maxLen) ? max : settings.maxLen);

        $(settings.elements.join(",")).css(settings.type, max + "px");
};

elemsEqual({elements : ['#selector1','#selector2', ... '#selectorN'], type : 'height'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have this so far:

```
//Get the height of the right column since it starts at a different Y position than the other two
var right=$('.right').outerHeight(1)-$('.left').children('header').outerHeight(1)-$('.left .innav').outerHeight(1);

//Get the max of the 3
var height_max=Math.max($('.leftCenter').outerHeight(1),$('.rightCenter').outerHeight(), right);

//Apply the max to all 3
$('.rightCenter').height(height_max-3); //-3 to accommodate for padding/margin
$('.right').height(height_max);
$('.leftCenter').height(height_max);
```

The only problem is that it does not make #newItemsList as tall as the parent, .leftCenter. It also assumes that the right div will be largest, so I don't know if it will still work if it isn't the biggest of the 3.